# Conflict between math.h and cmath?

Tags: c++

I have trouble compiling due to an "ambiguity".
I have:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

float q;
setActivacion(1/(1+pow(M_E,-q)));
```

Compiler says:
ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:

double pow(double, double) 
float std::pow(float, float)

I've tried plugging in straight decimal values into the arguments of pow() and it works. It just seems to have trouble taking a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cmath` is a wrapper of `math.h` for c++, you don't need both

Answer (score 2):

That's because the C++ standard library incorporates the C standard library - math.h and cmath shall be identical apart from the fact that cmath puts all the stuff in the `std::` namespace. So don't include both of them - if you're using C++, you should probably `#include <cmath>` **only**.

Comment: I usually add `<math.h>` because the most of implementations of `<cmath>` just include `<math.h>` and `using` function in `std` namespace.

Comment: @Naszta but that is to be done by the implementation as it's implementation-defined how it's implemented (yeah, I love this word!) Your error is a typical one when **eaxctly this** (i. e. relying upon implementation-defined behaviour) breaks your code.

Comment: basically I use this practice only with `<math.h>`. In this way I also should not care on `std` namespace. (+1 was added.)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that you should either pass in two floats, or two doubles. You are passing in a double and a float.

Try `pow(M_E, static_cast<double>(-q))`

For what it's worth, I can't get this error out of g++ (4.5.3). I can get a similar error out of Comeau, even if I only include one of the two headers (and regardless of which).

It may be there's some detail of gcc's implementation, that means there's only one matching version of `pow`. And it may be that on your compiler, including only one of the headers or specifying the namespace for `pow` removes the ambiguity too. But it's not usually a good idea to rely on a fix that depends on details of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `using namespace std;` in there somewhere don't you? You can also specify which version you want, i.e. `using std::pow` or `using ::pow` (syntax from memory, but hopefully you get the idea).